# Numpy float128 array/object operations returning overflow error

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am attempting to visualize a NeuralNetwork; class below. The code containing this segmant can successfully return a scatter plot and a curve (trained NN) with a randomly-generated input.  I've then inputted data from a .csv file and encountered overflow errors apparently due to very large or very small data values.

```
class NeuralNetwork:

  def __init__(self, width, activation_function):
    self.width=width
    self.activation_function=activation_function
    self.depth=len(width)-2
    self.W= np.array([np.random.randn(self.width[i+1],self.width[i]) for i in range(self.depth+1)], dtype=object)
    self.b= np.array([np.random.randn(self.width[i+1]) for i in range(self.depth+1)], dtype=object)
    self.alpha = 0.1 

  def sigma(self,x):
    if self.activation_function == 'Sigmoid':
      return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    else:
      if x>=0:
        return x
      else:
        return 0

  def d_sigma(self,x):
    if self.activation_function == 'Sigmoid':
      return self.sigma(x)*self.sigma(1-x)
    else:
      if x>=0:
        return 1
      else:
        return 0

  # vectorize the function
  def sigma_vec(self,X):
    return np.array([self.sigma(x) for x in X],dtype=np.float128)

  def d_sigma_vec(self,X):
    return np.array([self.d_sigma(x) for x in X],dtype=np.float128)

  def h(self,x):
    a=np.copy(self.b)  
    z=np.copy(self.b)
    z[0]=np.dot(self.W[0],x)+self.b[0]
    for i in range(self.depth):
      a[i]=self.sigma_vec(z[i])
      z[i+1]=np.dot(self.W[i+1],a[i])+self.b[i+1]
    return z[-1]

  def plot(self,plt,col):
    dx = np.linspace(0,1, 100)
    h_dx = np.array([ self.h([x]) for x in dx],dtype=np.float128)
    plt.plot(dx,h_dx,color=col)

  def gradient_of_loss_function(self,h,y):
    return h-y

  def gradient(self,x,y):
    a=np.copy(self.b)
    z=np.copy(self.b)
    z[0]=np.dot(self.W[0],x)+self.b[0]
    for i in range(self.depth):
      a[i]=self.sigma_vec(z[i])
      z[i+1]=np.dot(self.W[i+1],a[i])+self.b[i+1]
    gradient_b=np.copy(self.b)
    gradient_W=np.copy(self.W)
    gradient_b[-1]=self.gradient_of_loss_function(z[-1],y)
    for i in reversed(range(self.depth)):
      gradient_b[i]=np.dot(np.transpose(self.W[i+1]),gradient_b[i+1])*self.d_sigma_vec(z[i])
      gradient_W[i+1]=np.outer(gradient_b[i+1],a[i])
    gradient_W[0]=np.outer(gradient_b[0],x)
    return gradient_b,gradient_W;

  def batch_gradient(self,X,Y):
    batch_gradient_W=0
    batch_gradient_b=0
    for i in range(len(X)):
      gradient_b,gradient_W = self.gradient(X[i],Y[i])
      batch_gradient_W += gradient_W
      batch_gradient_b += gradient_b
    return batch_gradient_b,batch_gradient_W;

  def train(self,X,Y,iterate):
    for i in range(iterate):
      alpha= self.alpha/len(X)
      batch_gradient_b,batch_gradient_W =self.batch_gradient(X,Y)
      self.W -= alpha*batch_gradient_W
      self.b -= alpha*batch_gradient_b
```

Below is the code I am using to plot the data. The data is extracted from a csv file; I have made sure there are no NaN or 0 values within. `data_axis` and `data` are exported dates and stock market prices respectively.

```
X= np.array(data, dtype=np.float128).reshape(-1,1)
noise = np.random.randn(n)
Y= np.array(data_axis, dtype=np.float128).reshape(-1,1)

width=[len(X[0]),5,3,len(Y[0])]
nn=NeuralNetwork(width,'Sigmoid')

plt.scatter(X,Y,color='r')
nn.plot(plt,'b') #linear
nn.train(X,Y,10)
nn.plot(plt,'g') #curve plotted according to training
plt.show()
```

How may I edit the code so that a plotted curve may be drawn; and no overflow errors are returned?  I did ask a similar question yesterday; and I believe the source of the overflow to be in the input rather than the code. However, Numpy's Polyfit is able to return regression curves for the dataset - so I would imagine there is a way to eliminate overflowing through the code. Thank you for reading

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace for the error

Comment: The one remaining error message in stacktrace is ```RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp```